# Login to another application based on Yii Session

Tags: session, authentication, yii

What is the best way to check that I'm logged in to Yii from another application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your applications reside in the same server, using `$_SESSION` from the other application can allow you to access session variables set by your Yii application.

If you application doesn't reside in the same server, you may need to use a session database for that.

Comment: when I use `print_r($_SESSION);` I get `Array ( [TZ_OFFSET] => 2.0 [daylight] => [1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562__id] => 1 [1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562__name] => admin [1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562id] => 1 [1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562__states] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562first_login] => 1 )` how possibly can I make sure that this session is from my yii application?

Comment: Your Yii application prepends '1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562__' in front of variables. It's application specific. Alternatively, when our organization implemented single sign on, we specifically determine a key, e.g. `$_SESSION['Common']['user_id']`, to be present in the session.

Comment: I need to know how to get the prefix  '1a016e9e0bd34883178000505e0f6562__'

Comment: You can get that through CWebUser's `getStateKeyPrefix`. Alternatively, you can set it through `setStateKeyPrefix` too. More information: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#stateKeyPrefix-detail

Comment: a small but important correction - the two server don't need to be located on the same server but to be more accurate, need to use the same domain. Well, to be even more accurate:
(1) Both applications need to use the same session handling in PHP. If you don't know what I'm talking about then you're probably safe. Mark 'Pass' here on that case. (2) The Yii application session cookie needs to be set so that the other app would use it as well. Search for info on the web on session cookie domain in PHP etc. Finally, I would have went for some other (simple) syncing mechanism.